# Group sum and transform json object with values in nested array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, lodash

I am trying to aggregate and transform the following json :

```
[
{ 
    "orderId" : "01",
    "date" : "2017-01-02T06:00:00.000Z",
    "items" : [
        {
            "itemId": 100,
            "itemCost": 12,
            "itemQuantity": 10
        },
        {
            "itemId": 102,
            "itemCost": 25,
            "itemQuantity": 4
        }
    ]
},
{
    "orderId": "02",
    "date" : "2017-01-08T06:00:00.000Z",
    "items" : [
        {
            "itemId": 100,
            "itemCost": 15,
            "itemQuantity": 2
        },
        {
            "itemId": 101,
            "itemCost": 20,
            "itemQuantity": 5
        },
        {
            "itemId": 102,
            "itemCost": 25,
            "itemQuantity": 1
        }
    ]
},
{
    "orderId": "03",
    "date" : "2017-02-08T06:00:00.000Z",
    "items" : [
        {
            "itemId": 100,
            "itemCost": 15,
            "itemQuantity": 2
        },
        {
            "itemId": 101,
            "itemCost": 20,
            "itemQuantity": 5
        },
        {
            "itemId": 102,
            "itemCost": 25,
            "itemQuantity": 1
        }
    ]
}]
```

into an object that is grouped by itemId, and then aggregated by quantity, and aggregated by total cost (item cost * item quantity for each order) by month. Example:

```
[
    {
        "itemId": 100,
        "period": [
            {
                "month": "01/17",
                "quantity": 12,
                "cost": 130
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "itemId": 101,
        "period": [
            {
                "month": "01/17",
                "quantity": 5,
                "cost": 100
            },
            {
                "month": "02/17",
                "quantity": 5,
                "cost": 100
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "itemId": 102,
        "period": [
            {
                "month": "01/17",
                "quantity": 5,
                "cost": 125
            },
            {
                "month": "02/17",
                "quantity": 1,
                "cost": 25
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have a small indention on my desk in which I have been beating my head trying to figure how to do this using native map/reduce or lodash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this transformation:

```
const result = Object.values(myList.reduce( (acc, o) => {
    const month = o.date.substr(5,2) + '/' + o.date.substr(2,2);
    return o.items.reduce ( (acc, item) => {
        const it = acc[item.itemId] || {
                itemId: item.itemId,
                period: {}
            }, 
            m = it.period[month] || {
                month: month,
                quantity: 0,
                cost: 0
            };
        m.cost += item.itemCost * item.itemQuantity;
        m.quantity += item.itemQuantity;
        it.period[month] = m;
        acc[item.itemId] = it;
        return acc;
    }, acc);
}, {})).map( o => 
    Object.assign({}, o, { period: Object.values(o.period) }) 
);
```

```js
const myList = [
{ 
    "orderId" : "01",
    "date" : "2017-01-02T06:00:00.000Z",
    "items" : [
        {
            "itemId": 100,
            "itemCost": 12,
            "itemQuantity": 10
        },
        {
            "itemId": 102,
            "itemCost": 25,
            "itemQuantity": 4
        }
    ]
},
{
    "orderId": "02",
    "date" : "2017-01-08T06:00:00.000Z",
    "items" : [
        {
            "itemId": 100,
            "itemCost": 15,
            "itemQuantity": 2
        },
        {
            "itemId": 101,
            "itemCost": 20,
            "itemQuantity": 5
        },
        {
            "itemId": 102,
            "itemCost": 25,
            "itemQuantity": 1
        }
    ]
},
{
    "orderId": "03",
    "date" : "2017-02-08T06:00:00.000Z",
    "items" : [
        {
            "itemId": 100,
            "itemCost": 15,
            "itemQuantity": 2
        },
        {
            "itemId": 101,
            "itemCost": 20,
            "itemQuantity": 5
        },
        {
            "itemId": 102,
            "itemCost": 25,
            "itemQuantity": 1
        }
    ]
}];

const result = Object.values(myList.reduce( (acc, o) => {
    const month = o.date.substr(5,2) + '/' + o.date.substr(2,2);
    return o.items.reduce ( (acc, item) => {
        const it = acc[item.itemId] || {
                itemId: item.itemId,
                period: {}
            }, 
            m = it.period[month] || {
                month: month,
                quantity: 0,
                cost: 0
            };
        m.cost += item.itemCost * item.itemQuantity;
        m.quantity += item.itemQuantity;
        it.period[month] = m;
        acc[item.itemId] = it;
        return acc;
    }, acc);
}, {})).map( o => 
    Object.assign({}, o, { period: Object.values(o.period) }) 
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This was perfect. I had to convert Object.values using Object.keys since the version of node I am using doesn't support that extremely powerful and convenient method. I may end up using a polyfill for now.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```js
var orders = [{orderId:"01",date:"2017-01-02T06:00:00.000Z",items:[{itemId:100,itemCost:12,itemQuantity:10},{itemId:102,itemCost:25,itemQuantity:4}]},{orderId:"02",date:"2017-01-08T06:00:00.000Z",items:[{itemId:100,itemCost:15,itemQuantity:2},{itemId:101,itemCost:20,itemQuantity:5},{itemId:102,itemCost:25,itemQuantity:1}]},{orderId:"03",date:"2017-02-08T06:00:00.000Z",items:[{itemId:100,itemCost:15,itemQuantity:2},{itemId:101,itemCost:20,itemQuantity:5},{itemId:102,itemCost:25,itemQuantity:1}]}];

// First, map your orders by items
var items = {};
orders.forEach(function(order) {

    // set the month of each order
    var month = new Date(order.date);
    month = ('0' + (month.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' +  String(month.getFullYear()).slice(-2);
    
    // for each item in this order
    order.items.forEach(function(item) {
    
        // here we already have both keys: "id" and "month"
        // then, we make sure they have an object to match
        var id = item.itemId;
        if (!items[id]) {
            items[id] = {};
        }
        if (!items[id][month]) {
            items[id][month] = { cost:0, quantity:0 };
        }
        
        // keep calculating the total cost
        items[id][month].cost += item.itemCost * item.itemQuantity;
        items[id][month].quantity += item.itemQuantity;
    });
});

// Now, we format the calculated values to your required output:
var result = Object.keys(items).map(function(id) {
    var obj = {
        itemId: id,
        period: Object.keys(items[id]).map(function(month) {
            items[id][month].month = month;
            return items[id][month];
        }),
    };
    return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think the other answers out there do a pretty good job from the vanilla angle, so I wanted to take a stab at a more lodash-intensive approach since you mentioned it as a tag. This is mainly just a fun challenge, but I hope the solution is elegant enough for you to lift components from.

Before we begin, I'll be using both the vanilla lodash module and the [functional programming flavor](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) of lodash. Let `fp` be the functional programming module and `_` be vanilla (and let `orders` be your original data structure). Also, as a challenge, I'll do my best to minimize vanilla JS methods and arrow funcs to maximize lodash methods and function creation methods.

First, let's get all the items in a row, paired with their order information:

```
const items = _.flatMap(orders, o=> _.map(o.items, i=> [i, o]));
```

I know I said I wanted to minimize arrow functions, but I couldn't think of any other way to get the order object to the end of the chain. Challenge yourself to rewrite the above in terms of a composition (e.g. `fp.compose` or `_.flow`) and see what happens.

I'd say now's as good a time as any to group up our pairs by the item id:

```
const id_to_orders = _.groupBy(items, fp.get('[0].itemId'));
```

Here, `fp.get('[0].itemId')` gives us a function which, given an array, returns the `itemId` of the first element (in our case, we have a list of pairs, the first element of which is the item, the second of which is the relevant order object). Therefore, `id_to_orders` is a map from an item's ID to a list of all the times it was ordered.

This `id_to_orders` map looks pretty close to the data structure we're after. At a high level, all that's left is transforming the order data for each item into the quantity and cost, grouped by month.

```
const result = _.mapValues(id_map, fp.flow(
    // Arrange the item's orders into groups by month
    fp.groupBy(month)

    // We're done with the order objects, so fp.get('[0]') filters them
    // out, and the second function pairs the item's cost and quantity
  , fp.mapValues(fp.flow(
        fp.map(fp.flow(fp.get('[0]'), i=> [i.itemCost, i.itemQuantity]))

        // Sum up the cost (left) and quantity (right) for the item for the month
      , fp.reduce(add_pair, [0, 0])))

    // These last couple lines just transform the resulting data to look
    // closer to the desired structure.
  , _.toPairs
  , fp.map(([month, [cost, count]])=> ({month, cost, count}))
));
```

And the helpers `month` and `add_pair` referenced above:

```
function month([item, order]){
  const date  = new Date(order.date)
      , month = date.getMonth() + 1
      , year  = date.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);
  return `${month}/${year}`;
}

function add_pair(p1, p2){
  return [p1[0] + p2[0], p1[1] + p2[1]];
}
```

---

Just out of curiosity (or sadism), let's see what this whole thing would look like chained together as a single pipeline:

```
const get_order_data = fp.flow(
    fp.flatMap(o=> _.map(o.items, i=> [i, o]))
  , fp.groupBy(fp.get('[0].itemId'))
  , fp.mapValues(fp.flow(
        fp.groupBy(month)
      , fp.mapValues(fp.flow(
            fp.map(fp.flow(fp.get('[0]'), i=> [i.itemCost, i.itemQuantity]))
          , fp.reduce(add_pair, [0, 0])))
      , _.toPairs
      , fp.map(([month, [cost, count]])=> ({month, cost, count})))
));

const result = get_order_data(orders);
```

You'll notice this composed version has a lot more `fp` (as opposed to `_`). If you're curious why it's easier this way, I encourage you to read the [lodash FP guide](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide).

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0v9fhv1/1/) with everything.

---

Finally, if you'd like to transform the result from the code above *exactly* into the output format you mentioned in your post, here's what I recommend:

```
const formatted = _.keys(result).map(k=> ({itemId: k, periods: result[k]}));
```